# How to perform feature selection on text dataset before input them to model using Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, feature-selection

I am currently working on deep learning model for sentiment analysis on Twitter data. I am following this example from [Here](https://dzone.com/articles/sentiment-analysis-on-us-twitter-airlines-dataset)

To improve the accuracy **I want to perform feature selection on twitter text data before entering them as input** to the neural network model. I am working on tensorflow and keras.

How to achieve this using tensor-flow?

```
    data = tweets[['text','airline_sentiment']]
data = data[data.airline_sentiment != "neutral"]
data['text'] = data['text'].apply(lambda x: x.lower())
data['text'] = data['text'].apply((lambda x: re.sub('[^a-zA-z0-9\s]','',x)))

max_fatures = 2000
tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=max_fatures, split=' ')
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(data['text'].values)
X = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(data['text'].values)
X = pad_sequences(X)

embed_dim = 128
lstm_out = 196
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(max_fatures, embed_dim,input_length = X.shape[1]))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(LSTM(lstm_out, dropout=0.2, recurrent_dropout=0.2))
model.add(Dense(2,activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam',metrics = ['accuracy'])
print(model.summary())

Y = pd.get_dummies(data['airline_sentiment']).values
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X,Y, test_size = 0.33, random_state = 42)

X_val = X_train[:500]
Y_val = Y_train[:500]

partial_X_train = X_train[500:]
partial_Y_train = Y_train[500:]

batch_size = 512
history = model.fit(partial_X_train, 
                    partial_Y_train, 
                    epochs = 10, 
                    batch_size=batch_size, 
                    validation_data=(X_val, Y_val))
```

Comment: You mean, you want to limit the text tokens (words) and use "preselected" ones?

Comment: Yes. I want to do that. @Digital-Thinking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to do that. One simple idea would be to use TF-IDF as a metric for feature importance. You can use Keras Tokenizer to access the TF and IDF after you called `fit_on_texts`.

You can simply filter out values below some threshold: Take a look at [Text Preprocessing](https://faroit.github.io/keras-docs/2.0.2/preprocessing/text/)

Anyways, I would not suggest to go this path, as you are dealing with deep learning, your model should automatically learn this importance. Furthermore, you are using word embeddings, reducing the occurring word will impact these embeddings.

Your dictionary (max_fatures) is very low, I would first start increasing this number. Keras discards all other tokens:

> num_words: None or int. Maximum number of words to work with (if set,
>   tokenization will be restricted to the top num_words most common words
>   in the dataset)